# Different field data for different sites, does anyone know why?

Tags: pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

I've been working on improving our Core Web Vitals and thought I'd check another site to compare how we're doing.

I've noticed that one website has just the FCP, LCP, FID, CLS visible with a percentage image to represent how far away they are from the next stage. Yet, for our PageSpeed Insights Field Data we are seeing an additional 2 areas with Speed Index and Total Blocking Time, and we don't see the percentage image to help gauge.

Does anyone know how we can get ours to show the 4 main areas too please? I have attached images to show what I mean. Appreciate any help, thank you :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngi2e.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES13j.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your site's PSI results don't have any [**field data**](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#crux), and the two additional metrics you're seeing are actually the [**lab data**](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#lab) section. The other website may have more traffic than yours and qualify for inclusion in the public Chrome UX Report dataset, which could explain why they have field data in PSI but your site doesn't.

For example, here's a screenshot of the field and lab data sections:

[image: screenshot of PSI results lab and field data sections]

The field data section resembles your screenshot while the lab data section has additional metrics for SI, TTI, and TBT.

All pages tested in PSI will have lab data but only the pages/origins in the Chrome UX Report will have field data available.

For more info about the difference between lab and field data see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/speed-tools#understanding_lab_vs_field_data

Comment: Hi Rick, 

Ah thank you, that makes sense! I don't suppose you know roughly how many weekly/monthly visitors a website requires to get the field data metrics?

Also, just to check I understand this right, the metrics I'm getting right now are gathered from within my browser and network settings (so may not be a true representation of real world visitors), once we receive a larger amount of visitors we will start to see the field data from real life, public users?

Thanks again for your help.

Have a lovely day! 

:)

Ellie